# What's the difference between "IQueryable<T> Get()" and "IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)"

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, iqueryable

Given the following code is their any differences or reason to choose one way vs. another.  To me it seems that results1 and results2 would go through an almost identical process.  Am I missing something?  I've seen both ways in different source bases I was just curious if their is a good reason to choose one over the other.  Thanks.

```
public class Repo<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> items;
    public Repo(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }
    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return items.AsQueryable();
    }
    public IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return items.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        var repo = new Repo<string>(items);
        var results1 = repo.Get().Where(item => item == "b").ToList();
        var results2 = repo.Get(item => item == "b").ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's merely a convenience method, nothing more.

Comment: @JeffMercado - you should post your comment as the answer to this question.